# use mapbox geocoding in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geocoding, mapbox-gl

I need to use forward geocoding and reverse geocoding for mapbox in react-native.

is there any package or solution to do it?

Comment: Did you come up with anything? It's my situation right now.

Comment: Yep, you can check it in the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solutions to do that: 
it would be here, call API directly:

https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#geocoding

Comment: do you fix you problem already?  if yes how you fix ?